# Server Sent Events Not Working Using JavaFX WebView

Tags: reactjs, javafx, server-sent-events, javafx-webengine, eventsource

I have developed a single page application with React and MobX. To get some progress information from backend code such as copying a file progress, I use Server Sent Events and EventSource at javascript code. In any browser, I can get the event messages and show progresses successfully. React gets changes from the EventSource onmessage event and renders the changes on the screen. Here is how I add EventSource to my js code. (For the ones who ask if the message format of eventsource is correct? Yes, it is. It is working on browsers.)

Code:

```
    fetchEvents(url) {

        let evtSource = new EventSource(url);

        evtSource.onmessage = (message) => {
            const data = JSON.parse(message.data);
            //assign data to an observable variable
        }
    }
```

However, I need my single page application to be embeded in a Java application. For this, I use JavaFX WebEngine and WebView to load my React application. Every functionalities work well except Server Sent Events and EventSource messages. onmessage(), onopen(), onerror() methods are not called. Thus, I can't get the changes of data to be shown on the screen. I can't get any information via EventSource at my javascript code. Here is the JavaFX code;

Code:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        primaryStage.setTitle("localhost");

        WebView myBrowser = new WebView();
        WebEngine myWebEngine = myBrowser.getEngine();
        myWebEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebEngine.load("http://localhost:8080");

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().addAll(myBrowser, reloadButton);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 640));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Does JavaFX WebView not support EventSource and Server Sent Events? I am curious about is there any way to make SSE work in JavaFX WebView? Or are there any other possible solutions to embed my single page application in Java code with EventSource and Server Sent Events working well.

Thank you.